# Reload si falla la pregunta

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda y debe ser una tontería pero es que no entiendo porque pasa esto. Primero no controlo casi nada de javascript y no se si hay algo que estoy obviando.
El caso es que tengo una función donde si se acierta la pregunta un contador se incrementa. Lo que quiero hacer es que si falla vuelva a cargarse la página. El caso es que ahora mismo aunque se acierte se carga la página. Es un juego quiz donde si se acierta pasa la siguiente pregunta pero si se falla empiezas de nuevo.

```
//Funcion que compara los arrays para saber cuantas son correctas
function corregir(){
    
    cantidadCorrectas = "0";

    //Recorremos el array correctas y comparamos si la opcion elegida es igual la correcta en su indice.    
    for(i=0; i<correctas.length; i++){
     
        if(correctas[i] == opcionElegida[i]){
           //Si es igual cantidadCorrectas aumenta en 1
            cantidadCorrectas++;
            
        }else{
            location.reload();
        }     
        //Si se cumple esta condicion "correctas[i] == opcionElegida[i]" aparece la siguiente pregunta
        document.getElementById("p" + cantidadCorrectas).hidden = false;
    }
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = cantidadCorrectas; 
     
}
´´´
```

Comment: el problema radica en el for dado que seguira ejecutandose sea o no correcta y en algun momento alguna posicion no va a ser igual y saltara al else por lo que es tu logica la que falla, para estos casos es mejor una funcion aparte que valide y retorne true o false... si deseas una respuesta en codigo sugiero poner el contendido de las variables `correctas` y `opcionelegida`. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Conviene que incluyas un poco más del código que has escrito para entender el problema. Según cómo sea tu script, si utilizas un formulario para tu juego de "quiz" es muy posible que la causa de esas recargas de la página, no importa si el usuario acierta o falla, esté en el comportamiento por defecto del envío del formulario.

Puedes sobreescribir y prevenir el comportamiento por defecto del "submit" del formulario invocando `preventDefault()` al escribir el event listener.

```js
document.getElementById("guessForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      corregir();
});
```

En [este Codepen](https://codepen.io/alejandromad/pen/MWzwEJy) te he dejado un ejemplo, en este caso un juego básico de adivinar un número, con el que puedes hacer pruebas con las variables y funciones para comprobar el efecto de los cambios.

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué tal, Alfonso?

El problema es de lógica: Si para verificar que la opción elegida se encuentre dentro del arreglo de respuestas correctas vas a recorrerlo y comparar una por una, solo para la primera pregunta funcionaría el incremento del contador. Para la segunda pregunta, así la respuesta fuera correcta, se recargaría la página debido a que no coincidiría con el primer elemento del arreglo.

Lo mejor será que utilices el método [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```javascript
if (respuestasCorrectas.includes(opcionElegida)){
    //Se incrementa el valor del contador
}
else{
    //Se recarga la página
}
```

Un saludo